# Can I ask a question about Researchgate social network?

Tags: discussion, moderation, allowed-questions

Some members expressed concerns and criticized RG network,
is it alowed to open special topic about Researchgate, and to discuss about this problems?

Examples:

> There is actually an old ResearchGate question about this suggestion.
>   – agold yesterday
>
> Why would you prefer ResearchGate? They have a terrible reputation for shadiness and spamming. – MJeffryes yesterday  1
>
> No. No, no, no, no, no. Absolutely not. Do not post your data set on a site that spams its user base. – JeffE yesterday
>
> @JeffE: Could you explain more about the spamming, I'm intrigued to know. – Ébe Isaac yesterday 2
>
> ResearchGate are a commercial company with no clear method so far for making money. At some point, they're going to make a grab and try
>   to monetise whatever you do there, and it'll be a mess; there's no
>   guarantee that your content will remain there or remain accessible.
>   This is leaving aside the spamming problems that Jeff alludes to. –
>   Andrew yesterday

Comment: If you want to know whether your question would be on topic, it might help to say what your question *is*.

Comment: Why Researchgate have bad reputation according to members of this site? @ff524

Comment: That sounds like it would be closed as an opinion-based question - it's basically an invitation for others to share opinions, which is off topic here as described in the [help center](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Besides, existing questions like [ResearchGate: an asset or a waste of time?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16870/researchgate-an-asset-or-a-waste-of-time) and [Should I send a "cease-and-desist" letter to ResearchGate?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24127/should-i-send-a-cease-and-desist-letter-to-researchgate) already explain in great detail why so many academics dislike them.

Comment: Oh cool, I will take a look on it, thank for clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specific question you described in a comment,

> Why Researchgate have bad reputation according to members of this site?

sounds like it would be closed as an opinion-based question - it's basically an invitation for others to share opinions, which is off topic here as described in the [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Besides, existing questions like [ResearchGate: an asset or a waste of time?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16870/researchgate-an-asset-or-a-waste-of-time) and [Should I send a "cease-and-desist" letter to ResearchGate?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24127/should-i-send-a-cease-and-desist-letter-to-researchgate) already explain in great detail why so many academics dislike them.

Answer (score 2):

We have already a bunch of [questions and answers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsocial-media%5D+researchgate) about ResearchGate. So, if you have a new question, you can probably go on and ask. Be sure, however, that your question can be answered by the usual bunch of strangers on the Internet, who are just users of that service and for which certain details of its workings are totally unaccessible.

Comment: yes, but all this questions are general, nothing is discuss about security and reliability.

Comment: @SSimon from your meta question it wasn't clear that you were concerned about security and reliability. I don't think we can address these issues in a precise way.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't ask a question with the intent of having a discussion about *any* subject.

We're not a forum, and we're not here for discussion. We're here for specific questions with specific answers.

If you just want to chat, we have [a separate place for that](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2496/academia).

Comment: than why is there discussion tag?

Comment: @SSimon on Meta we have a discussion tag, to discuss the running of the main board. Having Meta and chat in addition  to the main site, keeps the main site discussion free, just like we like it.